# Commerce Kickstart cart errors

Tags: commerce

Our server tech moved a site (www.ontario-internet.com) and now clients can no longer add items to the cart.

If I log in as an admin, I can add items to the cart and the site works perfectly.  I'm not sure what permission might have been turned off or if there is a damaged file somewhere.
I have gone through the permissions and turned on anything to do with the cart.  As well, I went into the views and it looks like the Master Access Permissions are set to none.

When I try to search content I receive these errors:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 606 in user_node_load() (line 3662 of
>   /home/ontariointernet/public_html/modules/user/user.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3662 of
>   /home/ontariointernet/public_html/modules/user/user.module). Notice:
>   Undefined offset: 606 in user_node_load() (line 3663 of
>   /home/ontariointernet/public_html/modules/user/user.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3663 of
>   /home/ontariointernet/public_html/modules/user/user.module). Notice:
>   Undefined offset: 606 in user_node_load() (line 3664 of
>   /home/ontariointernet/public_html/modules/user/user.module). Notice:
>   Trying to get property of non-object in user_node_load() (line 3664 of
>   /home/ontariointernet/public_html/modules/user/user.module).

Can anyone help?  Should I supply any extra information?
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you cleared your cache?